# Problems with SubReport in Report Viewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

The problem is:
I use VS2013 and ReportViewer, in a Windows application  (C#) and i'm designing a Report that uses a subreport.
The problem is: I have a table, and a row, where i add the subReport ToolBox item. Then i go to the properties and select the "Use this report as a Subreport" option. It should show me a Browse button or a dropDown list, but there's neither.
The subReport is already created on a local folder, the same as the solution.

So, there's a way to use my local report as a subreport?? 
If there's no way, what should i do?

P.s. 1: I need to pass a parameter from the main report to the subreport.
P.s. 2: If someone knows a good tutorial about ReportViewer, please post the link.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using Crystal Reports? Crystal Reports is one of the best report designers and the company keeps updating and introducing new features. Most people use this so you should be able to find help easier.

Comment: @chris_techno25 While Crystal Reports may be good and all, this does not faintly help the OP.

Comment: Yeah, Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in designing of reports in SSRS reports it will not show a browse button it only shows a dropdown saying "use this report as a sub report.", here you need to add subreport control in the empty body space.

please see the following image, [image]

Comment: That's the problem. It doens't show the dropDown list. It just gives me a normal TextBox.

Comment: ok but i tried many ways it is always showing drop down but not a text box to rectify your problem, even if the reports project contains only one report then also it is showing drop down clearly,

Comment: Well, i checked on VS2012 and VS2013, and both don't show it. On a youtube video, the person is using VS2010 and it shows the DropDown. I'm assuming it as a change made is VS. I'm using StimulSoft reports now, in trial.  So far, it's the best report designer i used. By the way, thanks for the reply, @Guru!